# Latency in navigation when using d as l

Tags: vim

I am using a colmak layout and I am left-handed and therefore I have mapped `hlkj` to `rstd`.

Here are my navigation mappings:

```
noremap h d
noremap H D
noremap j s
noremap k t

noremap K T
noremap l r

noremap r h
noremap d l
noremap s gk
noremap t gj
```

Everything works pretty good except the navigation with the `d` key. When ever I press the `d` key, the `d` command appears in the lower right corner and after a second it turns into a `l` and the cursor moves right.

I want to get rid of the latency. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you just described is VIM entering in `Operation-Pending mode`. Probably you still have mappings for the `d` key. Type `:map d` and it will list all your mappings. Ex:

```
:map d
n  dm          * :<C-U>call signature#utils#Remove(v:count)<CR>
n  ds            <Plug>Dsurround
```

Now, just clear each mapping (or map it to your desired key). ex:

```
:nunmap dm
:nunmap ds
```

Do your remapping:

```
:nnoremap d l
```

Then, be happy!

Comment: You are right! I have the surround plugin installed. But I cannot use `nunmap ds` to unmap that because there is no such mapping at the time when my `vim.rc` is processed. I used `au VimEnter * nunmap ds` instead.